# Jquery not adding dynamic php

Tags: php, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I have a basic form that submits the form data to the same page and do a simple search in a MySQL db. The php for this in before the `<html>` tag

```
<body>
<div data-role="page">

<div role="main" class="ui-content"> 
enter code here
<table style="width:750px;">
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="player_documents_m.php" method="get" data-ajax="false">
        <tr style="height:35px;">
            <td style="width:250px; vertical-align:top; text-align:left;">
                <label for="name">Player Name: </label>
            </td>
            <td style="text-align:left; vertical-align:middle; text-align:center;">
                <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="inputs" size="45" value="<?php echo $my_name; ?>" maxlength="255"/>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr style="height:35px;">
            <td style="text-align:left; vertical-align:bottom; text-align:right;" colspan="2">
                <input type="submit" name="search" id="search" value="Search Player" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </form>
</table>
```

The above works in JqueryMobile

Then the results are added dynamically with html content but this does not work in JqueryMobile but taking out all JQueryMobile related stuff and leave a normal php page everything works.

Below the table tag above I add my php to add the founded search results.

```
<?php

    for($j = 0; $j < $i; $j++)
    {
        $photo = "images/" . $db_new . "/players/" . $player[$j]["player_id"] . ".jpeg";
        echo "<br />";
?>
    <!-- Search Results -->
    <div class="singleResult" onclick="javascript: window.location.replace('load_documents.php?identification=<?php echo $player[$j]["player_id"];  ?>');">
        <table border="1" style="width:100%; border: solid thin; padding:0; border-spacing:0;">
            <tr>
                <!-- Image 1st Column -->
                <td rowspan="2" colspan="1" style="width:10%; vertical-align:top; text-align:left;">
                        <img src="<?php echo $photo; ?>" style="width:150px; height:180px;" />
                </td>

                <td class="labels">Name:
                <p class="results"><?php echo $player[$j]["player_name"]; ?></p>
                </td>    
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <!-- End Of Search Results -->
<?php
    }

?>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Now the above only works normally and not in JqueryMobile. can some please explain to me what I am doing wrong / need to add, or anything helpful please.

Thanks

Comment: FYI: you have 2 conflicting `text-align` properties in your style attribute values.

Comment: can you show us your jquery code as well?